# How to add data in database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

There are two tables.

1. category(idcategory,name,url)
2. subcategory(id,name,url,idcategory)

In codeigniter I have the controller named submenu and view is vwsubmenu.
In add function I have to add the name, URL and the idcategory into the subcategory table.But in view page there is three field like one is input type text(name),input type text(URL),select type that is name of category from category table.

Now I want to take the id of category table from the name (which is the input of select type)and insert into subcategory table in idcategory field.
How to do that in codeigniter.

Please Help

Comment: add some code which you tired so far

Comment: I would suggest you studying [hierarchical data model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

This will return the last id from category table which then you can insert into sub category table.

You can get more info from [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

first improve your database structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `idcategory` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcategory`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

Try this ...

http://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-493.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function add_submenu()
 {

        if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
        {

        $namesubcategory=$_POST['namesubcategory'];
        $urlsubcategory=$_POST['urlsubcategory'];
        $parent_menu=$_POST['parent_menu'];
        $a=$parent_menu;
        $query = $this->db->query('Select idcategory from category where namecategory="$a"');
        $row = $query->row();
        $b=$row->idcategory;


        $sql="insert into subcategory values('','$namesubcategory','$urlsubcategory','$b')";
        $val = $this->db->query($sql,array($namesubcategory ,$urlsubcategory,$b));
        redirect('admin/submenu/');
        }

        $arr['page'] = 'submenu';

        $this->load->view('admin/vwAddSubmenu',$arr);
    }
```

this is the add function  in submenu controler

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to send data to model form controller

```
$result= $this->model_name->model_function($data);
```

Then you can specify this in model:

```
public function functionName( $data){
    $this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

load 3 input fields in subcategory view

1. name
2. URL
3. `idcategory`(this should be drop-down of the category table)

then add data to data base using provided settings.

**Code**

**before load subcategory view get `category` table** data in controller

```
$data['category'] = $this->Model_name->get_category();
$this->load->view('sub_category_view',$data);
```

In model

```
public function get_category()
{
    $query = $this->db->query->("SELECT * FROM category");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

In subcategory view

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/controller/add_subcategory">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Sub Category Name">
    <input type="url" name="url" value="Sub Category URL">
    <select name="category">
        <?php
            foreach ($category as $item)
            {
                ?>
                <option id="<?php echo $item['id'] ?>"><?php echo $item['name'] ?></option>
            <?php
            }
        ?>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Sub Category">

</form>
```

//adding sub category to database

In Controller

```
public function add_subcategory()
{

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);//if `mysqli` change this mysql_real_escape_string
        $url = $_POST['url'];
        $cat = $_POST['category'];


        $result = $this->Model_name->insert_subcategory($name,$url,$cat);

        if(isset($result))
        {
            echo 'insert successfully';

        }
        else
        {
            echo 'insert Failed';
        }

    }

}
```

In Model

```
function insert_subcategory($name,$url,$cat)
{
    $data = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'url' => $url ,
        'idcategory' => $cat
    );

    $this->db->insert('subcategory', $data);
}
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined variable: category
Filename: admin/vwAddSubmenu.php
Line Number: 48



A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning
Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: admin/vwAddSubmenu.php
Line Number: 48


   Dear Abdullah i write the code same as u hv written here but the error is shown in view page